# Custom styled label/checkbox on chrome not clickable

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a very strange behaviour only on Chrome. I want to style checkboxes on a filter layer. An example you can find on http://jsfiddle.net/2wpe0unu/

The filter criteria are dynamic and based on a REST call. It works perfect, but with some CSS3-features I'm using the labels cannot be clicked. To demonstrate this I've created a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/3oL5tmfp/1/ Open the Layer and try to click the checkbox.

Some thoughts to solve this problem:

1. `label` without `position: relative;` – it works, but the styled checkboxes are lost in space
2. `ul` without CSS-columns – it works, but I have no columns ;(
3. layer without `transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` – it works, but I do not have any hardware acceleration

The problem occurs only on Chrome (Mac & Windows) and Mobile Chrome (Android & iOS). It works like expected on IE10+, Safari, Mobile Safari and Firefox.

For me I've solved this by avoid `transform` on the layer (solution 3), but I would like to understand this strange behaviour.

May it's a bug of chrome engine? Any suggestions are welcome.

Ciao
Ralf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your ul add z-index: 2; and position: relative (to make the z-index work) seems to solve the problem in your fiddle.

Also would recommend adding a clearfix to your content is-open since you say the checkbox list will populate dynamically.

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks so much. I've added `position:relative` and a positive z-index and it works. And yes, a clearfix is used in the app. Ciao Ralf